# Add custom attributes to response with simplesaml

Tags: saml, simplesamlphp, idp

I'm setting up simplesaml as an IdP to do some testing for my SP. I need to add one new attribute to the response which is {sp_name}Access. However, I don't know where to add them.

I've tried adding the following to `saml20-idp-hosted.php`

```
'authproc' => array(
   50 => array(
       'class' => 'core:AttributeAdd',
       '{sp_name}Access' => '{sp_name}Access',
   ),
 )
```

And in my `authsources.php` I have this

```
'test-users' => array(
    'exampleauth:UserPass',
    'user1:user1pass' => array(
        'uid' => array('1'),
        'eduPersonAffiliation' => array('group1'),
        'email' => 'user1@example.com',
        'givenName' => 'User',
        'surname' => 'One',
        '{sp_name}Access => true
    ),
),
```

However it gives me this error

```
Backtrace:
1 www/_include.php:45 (SimpleSAML_exception_handler)
0 [builtin] (N/A)
Caused by: Exception: Invalid attributes for user user1 in authentication source test-users: Invalid attribute value for attribute loopioAccess: "1".
Backtrace:
6 modules/exampleauth/lib/Auth/Source/UserPass.php:55 (sspmod_exampleauth_Auth_Source_UserPass::__construct)
5 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:302 (SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::parseAuthSource)
4 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Source.php:343 (SimpleSAML_Auth_Source::getById)
3 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:56 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::getAuthSource)
2 lib/SimpleSAML/Auth/Simple.php:160 (SimpleSAML\Auth\Simple::login)
1 modules/core/www/authenticate.php:36 (require)
0 www/module.php:135 (N/A)
```

Any ideas how to actually add a custom attribute? I'm very new to simplesaml so I'm not sure if there's anything else I need to do to make this work.

Comment: attributes must be strings or arrays of strings. You are using a boolean `true`. You can switch it to a string `'true'` o `'1'`.

Answer (score 0):

Well, yout authsources.php IS missing a quotation mark after the key in the following key/value pair you provided... that could be a likely culprit.

'{sp_name}Access => true